# Jam is deprecated and has been removed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am new to Mac programming. I am trying to run a sample code I downloaded from
 http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/cocoa-distributed-objects-help-with-simple-problem.263315/
The code was written in 2002.I am trying to run the code in XCode6....I am getting the error-
'Jam is deprecated and has been removed; targets that use Jam must be upgraded to native targets. For more information on doing this, consult the Xcode documentation'.
Please help.

Comment: Code from 2002 is 13 years old, so it makes sense that it's not going to build immediately for you.  What kinds of errors are you getting?  What are you really trying to do?  What have you done on your own to try to fix this issue?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I am trying to run the code to see how Distributed Object works since the blog says its a simple example for Disributed Objects.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Like I said I am new to Mac programming so I am looking for solutions here....

Comment: _"please help."_ have you followed the instruction which was "For more information on doing this, consult the Xcode documentation", maybe? where are you stuck at during following that documentation? have you even started?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, JAM, this was legacy in Xcode from the very beginning and is a relict of Project Builder.

There has been a automatic conversion in the past. I do not know, whether it is still there. (Do you have a yellow triangle in the status bar? If so, click on it.) If there isn't an automatic conversion, I would create a new target and add all files that are in the JAM target to that.

However, I would chose a more modern example for an introduction to Xcode, Objective-C and Cocoa.

---

When you search for `NSDistantObject` in Xcode's documentation you will find sample code called Authenticator in the class' reference.

Or use this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/mac/d5e45b/samplecode/Authenticator/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...But there is not yellow triangle in the status bar...can please tell me where I can find a simple example on Distributed Objects?So that I can run it in my xcode and see the flow of it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Added a sample source.